# spresenseでFlashメモリへのファイル作成ができない時がある

Tags: spresense, arduino

現在、3軸加速度の値をspresenseメインボード上のflashメモリへ記録するプログラムをarduinoにて作成しています。しかし、ファイルが作成されたり,されなかったりと不安定です。その頻度は10回に1回程度です。先日の質問([Flashメモリに一定間隔で加速度の値を記録する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85536/))のように、数時間単位で何度もファイルを毎回open、closeをしてしまったため、Flashの寿命がきてしまったのでしょうか。それとも、何か別の原因があるのでしょうか。

行った手順としては
1.ファイルオープン後、Flush前、close前にログを発生させ,シリアルモニタで確認。
2.nuttx_shellを実行し、ファイルの有無を確認
3.ファイルがあれば、microSDカードに写し、中身を確認し、1に戻る。ない場合も1に戻る.

です。
この手順を行っても、ファイルが作成される場合とされない場合もログに変わりがありませんでした。

Comment: お使いのバージョンは最新でしょうか？v2.4.0への更新をオススメします。私も似たような問題に遭遇し最新にすると解消しました

Comment: kzzさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、Macを使用しているのですが、現在のバージョンの確認とバージョンの更新はどのようにして行えばよいのでしょうか。

Comment: ArduinoIDEのメニューからツール→ボード→ボードマネージャを開いてSpresenseを検索すると現在インストールされているバージョンを確認できます。アップデートしたいときは、バージョンを選択してインストールを実行すればアップデートできます。

Comment: v2.4.0へアップデートを行い、動作を確認してみましたがFlashへの記録がされず、解決には至りませんでした。

Comment: フラッシュメモリには寿命があると先の質疑応答で書きましたが、まあフツーに使う限りにおいては（プログラムの誤りなどにより）連続的に書き込みを繰り返しても数か月は何の問題もなく動くので（実力上は数十万回の消去が問題なくできる）何かあるとしたらあなたのプログラムなり、開発環境なり、使用しているライブラリの問題でしょう。

Comment: 破損や寿命の可能性もゼロでは無いけど、客観的に判断する材料が無いので (第三者が) フラッシュメモリに対しての見解を述べるのは難しいかと。可能であれば別のメモリを試して結果がどうなるか調べる…とかになるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

KX122センサを持っているので、同じソースコードで`KX126`を`KX122`に変更しただけのものを動かしてみましたが、特に問題無く動作します。30秒周期で`dataFile.flush()`するタイミングで"4hz60.txt"ファイルにデータが追加されています。ファイルの中身をみても250ミリ秒ごとにデータが入っています。(このスケッチ内でファイルの消去はされていないので、繰り返し実行したりリセットしたりすると常に後ろに追記されています)

「Flashへの記録がされたりされなかったりと不安定」が一切データが書き込まれていないのか、一部のデータが欠けているのか、時間が飛んでいるのか、具体的な内容が分かりませんが、もしFlashの問題でしたら、Flashの操作だけを行って切り分けした方が良いと思います。

もしまだ試していなければ、Flashをフォーマットすると復旧するかもしれません。"Spresense用のスケッチ例" -> "Flash" -> "format" スケッチでフォーマットできます。フォーマットするといままで取得したFlash内のデータはすべて削除されるのでご注意ください。

Comment: kzzさん返信が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。コメントありがとうございます。Flashへはファイルがまず作成されていない状況となっております。フォーマットをしてみたのですがそれでも、作成されないケースがありました。

Comment: フォーマットしても復旧しないということはFlashが物理的に壊れたのでしょうか...。センサは外して、Flashライブラリのサンプルスケッチ "Flash" -> "read_write" さえも動作しない状況ですかね?? Spresenseのバージョンはv2.4.0に上げていますよね。v2.3.1以前だとファイルの書き込みに失敗することがありましたが、v2.4.0だと問題なく使えています。

Comment: センサを取り外し、read_writeを動作50回動作させたところ、全て書き込めていました。arduino spresenseのバージョンは2.4.0です。

Answer (score 0):

まずはそのファイルのデータを読み込み、保存して、どこがどういうふうに違っているかを確認しては。

Answer (score 0):

私もFlashを結構使うほうで、データが書き込めない症状に何度か陥ったことがあります。その時に解決した方法を備忘録としてご参考までにここに記載しておきます。

**＜復帰手順＞**

1. Spresenseのrecovery_toolで工場出荷状態にする
2. Bootloaderを書き込む
3. SpresenseのFlashサンプルのFormatでFlashをフォーマットする
4. Flashサンプルのread_writeで動作確認する

recovery_toolの場所はとても分かりにくいのですが、ヘルプにリンクがあります。

**Spresense FAQ**
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/faq_ja.html

このFAQの`Spresense のシリアルモニタに "D>" と表示されてしまう、またはボードへの書き込みに失敗する`に詳しく解説されています。念のためRecovery_toolのダウンロードページへのリンクも張り付けておきます。

**Recovery_toolのダウンロードページ**
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/spresense-recovery-tool

使い方はダウンロードしたZIPファイルを解凍するとマニュアル同梱されているのでそちらを参照してください。